# is the whole shell script a "complete command" by the grammar?

Tags: shell, posix, yacc

This is a dumb question I know that, and I think intuitively I know the answer, but I can't find it confirmed by any independent documentation.

If you look at the official POSIX shell grammar, it has a start symbol like this:

```
%start  complete_command
%%
complete_command : list separator
                 | list
                 ;
```

So, wait, if we have a shell script, then, the whole script is one giant "complete command" by the rules of the grammar?  Is that right?

Comment: The Bison manual documents the Bison framework for writing programming language grammars, not the POSIX shell grammar. You seem to be vaguely barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @tripleee here's why I said that - the grammar in the POSIX shell standard, uses yacc/bison syntax.  My question may be restated as : "what does this syntax mean".  Therefore, the answer may well be in their manual(s)

Comment: Pretty much any meaningful grammar will have a production like this; it is how we make recursive-descent parsers. Basically, if the top-level production isn't recursive, the language is enumerable, in which case a grammar is overkill for describing it.

Comment: Please re-open and migrate to the Unix stackexchange, or Programmers.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, a [older version of the POSIX documentation (1997)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/chap2.html) stated:

> The start symbol of the grammar (**complete_command**) represents either
>   input from the command line or **a shell script**.

but this is no more present in the current specifications.

Recent [POSIX discussions](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1055&nbn=4) seem to imply a shell script should actually be considered as a sequence of `complete_commands`:

> Once a complete_command symbol has been recognized by the grammar (see
>   [xref to 2.10 Shell Grammar]), the **complete_command** shall be subjected
>   to alias substitution (see [xref to 2.3.1 Alias Substitution]) then
>   executed **before the next complete_command is tokenized and parsed**.

Comment: Thank you.  Your answer pointed me in the right direction, namely - to the stupidity of my question.

Comment: I don't think your question is stupid. The fact the POSIX standard writers were initially wrong is on the opposite show the answer is not that obvious. I don't think your question is off topic either, questions about programming languages formal grammar descriptions interpretation are imho perfectly on topic here.

Comment: What may very well be happening, is that initially the grammar was such that, the whole script was a "complete command" at that time.  Then, the standard got revised (it does many times) and now, the answer is different, and the fora comments are different.

Comment: @MarkGaleck The 1997 and the current grammar are almost the same and in any case, the differences between them do not change the *complete_command* interpretation. Only the *case/esac* and *else* statements descriptions are slightly different.

Comment: So why don't they roll this into the grammar, darn it?  `script : command | script command | /* empty */ ;`.   The expansion of aliases and all that is just the semantic action for `command`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dumb question like I said at the beginning...  I could delete it but - that would not account for the effort of jlliagre , whose answer led me to discover where the dumbness lies.

The grammar fragment I posted, is insufficient to answer the question.  The whole grammar is really needed.  If one studies the whole grammar carefully, then one can see that the answer must be:

No, the whole script is not a "complete command".  A "complete command" is recognized at the start of input, and then the next one possibly, and so on.